# What part of speech are "answer" and "enough" in this sentence?

Tags: articles, determiners, parts-of-speech

> Sirius suggested once, without any real conviction, that they all go to bed, but the Weasleys' looks of disgust were **answer enough**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't understand the grammar about "*the Weasleys' looks of disgust were **answer enough***". Is 'answer' here a noun word, and 'enough' an adverb or a determiner? If 'answer' is a noun, why doesn't it take any articles? E.g. "*the Weasleys' looks of disgust were the answer enough*".

Another question:  is it the same to write it as "the Weasleys' looks of disgust **answered (that) enough**"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Answer enough*** is a common phrase in English. I won't say figure of speech, because it's not metaphorical or ungrammatical or anything - it just doesn't match patterns that are widely used otherwise.

***Enough***, here, is a determiner. It means *sufficient*, not less than is necessary. Determiners often remove the need for an article. Most determiners go before their nouns, but enough is often used *after* the relevant noun:

> Are you man **enough** for her?
>   I have money **enough** for a good meal.
>   I'm pedant **enough** to go around correcting people's grammar.

These might all be rephrased:

> Are you **enough of a** man for her?
>   I have **enough** money for a good meal.
>   I'm **enough of a** pedant to go around correcting people's grammar.

We can see that, for a mass noun, it can just go before or after. For a countable noun, however, or an always-singular noun, if it goes after the noun there's no other words, but if it goes before you need ***of*** and the appropriate article.

Thus, the example in your question can be rephrased:

> ...but the Weasley's looks of disgust were **enough of an** answer.

Now, there's the question of "enough for what?", but that's a whole other kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

> *Sirius suggested once, without any real conviction, that they all go*
>   *to bed, but the Weasleys' looks of disgust were answer enough.*

"Answer" belongs to the category noun, "enough" to the category determinative.

The sufficiency determinative "enough" is not permitted in pre-head modifier position. But it has the syntactic peculiarity of being able to appear as post-head modifier of nouns (as well as adjectives and adverbs), as seen in your example. The fact that no article is required is probably just a feature of this idiomatic NP.

We might more naturally paraphrase informally it as "but the Weasleys' looks were a sufficient response".